# Double Jquery Slider UI to output integers after first input

Tags: php, jquery

Hopefully I can explain this clearly.

I'm looking to have a two sliders, and the output on the second slider depends on the first sliders output.

Firstly, the user sets a price on the first slider, then the user uses a second slider to set the number of customers allowed to purchase and item,  the second slider should output only whole numbers from the calculation.

For example. Price is set to £50. Then second slider should then output 1,2,5,10,25,50 as these are the only whole numbers from the calculation.

I'm stumped!

Comment: maybe for the second slider, you should not use a slider. as far as I know sliders are good for increments that's the same, in your case you have increments that are different

Comment: I'm looking sown the lines of is_integer - perhaps none of them need to be sliders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#slider1, #slider2").on("slidechange", function() {
       var value1 = $('#slider1').slider('value');
       var value2 = $('#slider2').slider('value');

       // your computation here = outputVar

       $('#output').text(outputVar);
 });
```

Something like this should work for you. Basically listen for the user changing the value of the slider, get your values, and output them somewhere on the page.